# How do you check a string so that it contains only certain amount of numbers and characters

Tags: python

Hi all was wondering how I make a program to check a string so that it only contains 2 or 3 numbers and 4 letters.

Example

```
string = input("Please enter a string: ") #example string would be HY21 4KK  
if  
string contains 2-3 characters
string contains 4 letters  
print("This is valid")  
else   
Print("This is invalid")
```

the simpler the better, because im really new to programming

Comment: With "charecters" you mean *digits*? The title and code are contradictory. "charecters and letters" is not "numbers and charecters".

Comment: Maybe first learn how to produce correct Python code with indentation and colons and lower case `print` statements.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I believe that this python code is rather pseudo-code and not python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply loop through all letters, sum how many there are, and the same for all digits, and then check if it matches your conditions, something like this:

```py
import string

# string.ascii_lowercase is "abdcdef..."
# string.ascii_uppercase is "ABCDEF..."
# so string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase will be all lowercase letter, and then all uppercase letters.
# string.digits is "01234567890"

e = input("Please enter a string: ")
# Here we will sum the number of appearances of every letter, lower case or upper case, in the English alphabet
# to get the total number of letters in e:
letter_count = sum(e.count(i) for i in string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase)
# Same here except with all digits:
digit_count = sum(e.count(i) for i in string.digits)

if digit_count in [2, 3] and letter_count == 4:
    print("This is valid")
else:
    print("This is invalid")
```

Comment: thank you i appreciate this i will confirm answer as soon as the site lets me.

Comment: You should also edit your question, to fix the inconsistency with the words "numbers", "letters", "characters"

Comment: "the simpler the better, because im really new to programming" - I doubt that OP is able to understand what this code does. I hardly understand it.

Comment: Perhaps, updated with comments to clarify.

Comment: "sum the count of i within e" - that's what the code already says. But what is `i` and why do we need to count that in `e`? Why convert the user input to lowercase? If it's a password, you might not want a lowercase only password.

Comment: All correct, updated again, thanks.

Comment: if i dont understand what it does i do have google which i used to understand the import function and now i know what that does it adds to what i can do and understand and now i can go back and further simplify older code i have written using it. understna dim here to learn new things in codeing nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @Yuval.R thank you for your help i understood the code just had to see what the import does and appreciate your help and teaching please keep doing what your doing out of all the comments yours was the most helpful and makes me want to learn more and understand how to ask questions and clearify them.